# Display M and F summaries horizontally in report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am using an aggregated query to generate a report based on gender. My query works fine and generates the following result:

```
New Comers M 10
New Comers F 5
```

I am using crystal reports and want to display the above as:

```
             M         F     
New Comers   10        5
```

Any idea please? The data comes from SQL SErver 2008

Answer (score 1):

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    col1 /* new comers */
  , M = count(case when gender = 'M' then 1 end)
  , F = count(case when gender = 'F' then 1 end)
from t
group by col1
```

or using `sum()` to return `0` instead of `null` when none are found:

```
select 
    col1 /* new comers */
  , M = sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end)
  , F = sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your problem : You need the rows of the column 1 to appear as column headers instead. If i'm interpreting it right, solution to your question lies in using `PIVOT`
As MS descirbes it :

> PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values
>   from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output,
>   and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining
>   column values that are wanted in the final output.

For syntax and other details you may refer [official documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.130).aspx)